# VARCHAR vs DECIMAL Performance

Tags: sql-server

Our database is SQL Server 2008. For some reason, the DBA (now long gone) made all of our primary keys `DECIMAL(38,0)`. These columns are not specified as identity columns--rather, there is a formula in the application code generates the unique identifier (random number) for the column.

We're obviously not going to get away from having a 38 digit number as the primary key for our data any time soon. And really, the concept is just fine. The number should be as statistically random (if not even more random) than the `uniqueidentifer` type, we just don't have the convenience of generating the number without the application code.

My question is: If I were to convert these `DECIMAL(38,0)` columns to `VARCHAR(38)`, would there be any advantages in index size, index speed, data retrieval speed, storage requirements, etc...? We don't need to do any math on these columns, so it really seems like a waste to have them be a `DECIMAL(38,0)`.

I'm more of an application developer than a DBA, so forgive me if this sounds like an ignorant question.

Comment: I would think you'd see a performance hit. You're going from 17 bytes of data to 38 bytes of data.

Comment: FYI, even guids (uniqueidentifers) are just numbers under the hood...

Comment: What's broke? Are you trying to convert to varchar for what benefit?

Comment: Why would it be slower to sort and index number vs text? It's all bytes in the end and the less you compare, the faster it works. Anyway, using random numbers for PK is not good idea (performance-wise), as inserts into middle of the table are generally slower, than adding a row to it's end.

Comment: Nope, numbers are always faster than text when it comes to database.

Comment: @n0rd In my head, the sorting algorithm went something like this in a loop: `1 == 1`, `12 == 12`, `123 != 124`, `next`. But yeah, now that I think about it, what you're saying is true. I guess if it's comparing the two numbers for sorting purposes, both numbers have to be entirely loaded in memory anyway. It's not like I would be saving any memory by doing an ASCII value-based sort.

Comment: Think like this: a varchar(38) is something like 38 byte number or about 90 decimal digit number. There is no chance this to be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You are not likely to see any storage improvement. A `decimal(38,0)` takes 17 bytes each. A `varchar(38)` can take up to 40 bytes (actual data length + [2 bytes overhead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms176089.aspx)). Performance is harder to measure but the FPGA on modern CPUs are made to calculate floating point numbers so I naturally expect a big boost for `decimal`.

One last thing:

> The number should be as statistically random (if not even more random) than the `uniqueidentifer` type

Most random number generators are pseudo-random. They are OK but not great. If your application lives or dies by the quality of the random numbers, try a crypto-level random number generator.